# How to use the custom fields of the organizer in the email template of the WP EVENT MANAGER plugin?

Tags: wordpress, events, plugins, key

I create a website for mountain guides who propose weekly outings. The goal is that people can register online for these outings.

To do this, I use the plugin WP EVENT MANAGER.

The plugin proposes to create custom fields for the event creation form and for the organizer form.

But the problem is that I can't get the data from the organizer's custom fields to introduce them in the automatic emails.

The plugin offers some dynamics tags like [organizer_name] or [organizer_email] but not more. While for the event it is possible to search any custom field with the following dynamic tags: [event_post_meta key="_event_location"].

I already tried to change this dynamic tag to [organizer_post_meta key="_organizer_phone"] but it doesn't work.

Can you help me?